# Joining 2 PDFs using Python join.py results in blank PDF

Tags: python, pdf

When I run join.py on computer A, I get a properly joined 2 page PDF. When running it on computers B and C, I get a one page blank PDF. All three computers are MacBook Pros running 10.10.1

Running the following command from Script Editor, **no errors occur**:

```
do shell script "python '/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py' -o '/Volumes/SSD/Users/username/Desktop/CD123AD9-77DB-4678-B301-9498CFD4E344/Welcome Packet.pdf' /Volumes/SSD/Users/username/Desktop/CD123AD9-77DB-4678-B301-9498CFD4E344/*.pdf"
```

Any ideas on what is causing the joined PDF to come out as 1 page and blank?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO!  If join.py is someone else's code (unless it's a development utility) then this question is off-topic for this site.  However, if join.py something you wrote, then please show enough of it that we might figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't matter who wrote `join.py`, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but i had the exact same problem. After a lot of different attempts, eventually i managed to solve it (with the help of SO users ofc - thanks Marcomdm) in the following way:

I created a string with the necessary command parameters laid out:

```
stringToCall = "%s %s %s%s" % ("./join.py -o", endPdf, pdfInputDir,"/*.pdf")
        os.chdir(/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/)
        os.system(stringToCall)
```

where endPdf is the final pdf name coming from
`endPdf = os.path.join (pdfOutputDir, pdfName+".pdf")`

Worked like a charm. Hope this helps.